# Mixing typedefs and defines to force data type sizes

Tags: c, gcc, types

I'm doing module testing of code written for a different platform and are having a problem where I need to constrict the sizes of the data types in the module being tested. Since I can't modify the module file directly I thought of using stdint.h typedefs and replace the modules declaration using defines. In essense this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define int int16_t

int main() {
    uint16_t ui = 2;
    unsigned int uii = 3;
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("Test %d, %d\n", ui, uii);
    return 0;
}
```

However this fails with this message:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘uii’
```

Is there another way to do this kind of type replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `signed`, `unsigned`, `long`, `short` modifiers can only be applied to the keywords that denote built-in types. They can't be applied to a typename that happens to be an alias for a built-in type: the C syntax doesn't allow it.

As for what you *can* do, I think Mysticial's answer covers it. Changing the size of `int` will conflict with whatever ABI the compiler is using to make library and system calls, so you can't really do it without compiler support. For example suppose you have a function declared as follows:

```
int foo(int a);
```

If you replace all mentions of `int` with `short` in the TU that calls that function, but not the TU that implements it, then the caller will pass and receive a `short`, whereas the function implementation expects and returns an `int`. This won't necessarily work. You need all libraries, including the standard libraries and any system calls they make, to be compiled such that caller and callee agree what an `int` is.

One option of course is to change all the code you're testing, to use macros in place of `int`, `unsigned int`, and so on. Then any function declarations in headers are left alone. There will be implicit conversions when the types won't match, which might provoke compiler warnings and truncate values, but at least has defined behavior. Basically it's dependency injection via the preprocessor.

Comment: This will work for basic integers but fail horribly for long. I tried substituting long for int which results in complains about "int doubles". The end result is that it will be much easier changing the TU to not rely on data sizes than to struggle with equal types having different sizes for different parts of the code.

Answer (score 3):

For why your particular example fails it's because it's being expanded to:

```
unsigned int16_t uii = 3;
```

with which the `unsigned` modifier apparently doesn't work on `int16_t`.

**Now to answer the question:** I don't think you can do this unless the compiler has an internal option to change the size of `int`. Trying to force it will clash with internal library functions.

For example: Your `printf()` will also break because `%d` is going to expect the normal `int`, but you pass it a 16-bit integer.

EDIT: This `printf()` example is not a good example since `int16_t` will be promoted to `int`. But the general idea still holds. (see comments)

Comment: But the int16_t is a typedef which expands to short int, so the line should end up being interpreted as unsigned short int which should be very legal, no?

Comment: I just tried it in VS2010, it doesn't work through a typedef. (But it does through a macro of course...)

Comment: Yes. I just think the stdint types are a cleaner way of writing it.

Comment: @Kenneth: no, because `signed`, `unsigned`, `long`, `short` modifiers can only be applied to the keywords that denote built-in types. They can't be applied to just any old typename that happens to be an alias for a built-in type, the C syntax doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Mystical: possibly a bad example, since `int16_t` is promoted to `int` anyway in varargs. The general point is correct, though. It's undefined behavior to use a keyword as the name of a macro, and one kind of bad behavior that you can expect as a result is that calling conventions will break because the TU with the `#define` in it has a different idea what the parameters are, compared with the TU containing the function.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know smaller integer types get promoted to `int`. (I knew about `float` -> `double`, but not for `int`.) Guess I learned something new today. :)

Comment: @Steve: You typedef comment is the answer the question. Would you mind creating an answer for it, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Kenneth: `int16_t` is a typedef for (on your system) `short int`.  That means `int16_t` is a type name.  It's *not* a macro.  It doesn't expand to the token sequence `short` `int`.  Rather, both `short int` and `int16_t` are names for the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use

**#define int *short***

instead.